# Issue with decoding characters in API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

Having some trouble handling values coming from an external API service with Node.

```
http.get(
    endpoint,
    function(res)
    {
        if (res.statusCode != 200)
        {
            return next();
        }
        var pageData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on(
            'data',
            function(chunk)
            {
                pageData += chunk;
            }
        );
        res.on(
            'end',
            function()
            {
                waterfallCallback(null, pageData);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I'm then deserializing the string with a xml2js parser and using the data accordingly. A few of my strings have foreign characters in them ie. Ciné when they get saved to db they don't record correctly.

I've attempted using the iconv package to convert from utf-8 to ISO-8859-1 but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle a situation.

Help by an expert is appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: You are setting the encoding to utf-8. Are you sure the server returns utf-8 encoded strings? Is this res object reading the return mime-type and would work okay if you would not set the encoding manually? I do not know which API you use ;-(

Comment: It actually doesn't matter which API it is, as long as your application is only able to handle ISO-xxxx-x you will always run in to problems like this. You might fiddle around with encoding/decoding routines but on the long run you need to go at least with UTF-8 entirely (database, web server, php, application, ...). It's a lesson I had to learn as well :-(

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for your help guys. I'm removing my setEncoding now. The API isn't actually returning an encoding type (at least not in the headers). Do you think I should change my method perhaps?Specify the ISO then convert to UTF-8? Sorry I think I'm just having trouble determining what to do when I have an unknown encoding. Here's a sample of the data that's returned: http://pastebucket.com/15770

Comment: lol oh man, a colleague just pointed out that the XML declaration states the encoding directly (ISO-8859-1). I totally missed that. Lesson learned: understand your data fully before working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this going. Lesson learned: *always* understand the data your dealing with. Not just the format/structure but character encoding is absolutely vital.

The main issue was that characters were being sent as ISO-8859-1 but I had no idea. Once I found that out I converted everything to UTF8 which the database and all my own API endpoints serve up.

I changed my call to use the request node package, pulled it down as binary and used iconv to convert to UTF8. Here's some helpful code:

```
request(
    {
        uri: 'http://' + endpoint.host + endpoint.path,
        encoding: null
    },
    function(err, response, body)
    {
        if (! err && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            var iconv = new icon('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF8');
            var converted = iconv.convert(body);

            callback(
                null,
                converted.toString('utf8')
            );
        }
        else
        {
            next();
        }
    }
);
```

The returned result is now exactly what I'm expecting. =)